# WM_NCLBUTTONUP message not sent at the end of dragging a form, how to do so?

Tags: c#, winforms, wndproc

**EDIT:** tl;dr go to the first comment.

This question stems from another question of mine [Get MouseDown event when mouse goes down on Form border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459360/get-mousedown-event-when-mouse-goes-down-on-form-border)

In that question I needed to have a form fire an event when the user pushed the left mouse button down on the form border (preparing to drag), which works perfectly. The problem is when the user has finished this action, by letting go of the left mouse button, I would also like to have an event fired.

To do so I produced this code to be placed in a "base form" class that other forms would be derived from. I have removed the `FireMouseButton...()` methods for succinctness; they fire custom events.

```
const int WM_NCLBUTTONUP = 0xA2;
const int WM_NCLBUTTONDWN = 0xA1;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONUP)
        FireMouseButtonUp();
    if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDWN)
        FireMouseButtonDown();
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

The problem with this is that the `WM_NCLBUTTONUP` message is not sent as I expected it. After reviewing the description for `WM_NCLBUTTONUP` I can see why though,

> [WM_NCLBUTTONUP is] posted when the user releases the left mouse button while the cursor
>   is within the nonclient area of a window. This message is posted to
>   the window that contains the cursor. If a window has captured the
>   mouse, this message is not posted.

Because the form has captured the mouse while it is being dragged, it will not receive the `WM_NCLBUTTONUP` message. (It will if the form is maximized though). This question explains it a little better [The curious problem of the missing WM_NCLBUTTONUP message when a window isn't maximised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521147/the-curious-problem-of-the-missing-wm-nclbuttonup-message-when-a-window-isnt-ma).

The answer to that question is somewhat helpful but causes a lot of confusion for me. In the code below I have a small SSCCE, it implements some code given from the solution to the answer above, checking the `WMNCHITTEST` message to see if the mouse has been released;

The idea is that the `WM_NCHITTEST` should be sent when the mouse is moving within the form. So once a drag stops this message should be sent with the mouse position as `DragStartPoint` in the WndProc message arguments; where `DragStartPoint` is recorded when the `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` message is received.

The issue with this though is that the `WM_NCHITTEST` is not always sent after the start of a drag, only when the drag is started on the far sides of the top border (see pic below). The `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` message is always sent when clicking on the top border (never for sides or bottom). So that is fine, but the `WM_NCHITTEST` and as pointed out `WM_NCLBUTTONUP` are sent, but only sometimes.

[image]

How might I get the `WM_NCHITTEST` "test" to work in the code below so that I can be notified once the user has stopped dragging the form? (the "test" being checking the `DragStartPoint` in the if statement for `WM_NCHITTEST`)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MouseEventTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
        const int WM_NCLBUTTONUP = 0xA2;
        const int WM_NCLBUTTONDWN = 0xA1;

        public Point DragStartPoint { get; set; }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONUP)
            {
                label1.Text = "Mouse Up On Border";
            }
            if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDWN)
            {
                label1.Text = "Mouse Down On Border";

                Point pos = lParamToPoint(m.LParam);
                DragStartPoint = this.PointToClient(pos);

                Console.Out.WriteLine("DragStartPoint: " + DragStartPoint);
            }

            if(m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
            {
                Point pos = lParamToPoint(m.LParam);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("HtTestPnt: " + this.PointToClient(pos));

                if (DragStartPoint == this.PointToClient(pos))
                {
                    label1.Text = "Mouse Up HitTest";
                }
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        private Point lParamToPoint(IntPtr lParamIn)
        {
            int x = lParamIn.ToInt32() & 0x0000FFFF;
            int y = (int)((lParamIn.ToInt32() & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
            return new Point(x, y);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(42, 30);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(91, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "99999999999999";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(185, 75);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use WM_EXITSIZEMOVE to detect that Windows stopped the modal loop.  Pretty easy to discover this by yourself when you use the Spy++ utility btw.

Comment: @HansPassant Again, beautiful solution. If you'd like the "best answer" points, I'd be glad to accept it. // Hmm, just looked at the overview for Spy++ looks like I'll have to try that out today.

Comment: Could you kindly post code for the solution? I'm not quite sure how to interpret that.